# MongoDB - Failed to unlink socket Fatal Assertion

Tags: 18.04, nodejs, mongodb

`2020-02-20T18:39:33.644+0530 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5391 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=himanshu-pc
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 E  NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 40486 at src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp 683
2020-02-20T18:39:33.651+0530 F  -        [initandlisten]`

***aborting after fassert() failure

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely your problem:

`NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating`

Your configuration points to a data directory (`/data/db`) which does not exist.
Either create this directory or edit your configuration to a valid data directory.

Comment: Please don't expect a step-by-step tutorial.
Read the documentation on mongodb configuration and come back with further questions.